# Laravel Debugbar messages not showing

Tags: php, laravel-5

L5.0

I have the DebugBar installed, and it's working and showing at the bottom of the screen. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to send messages to the console to show up under "Messages"

I've tried the following in my controllers...

```
use DebugBar\DebugBar;
....
DebugBar::addMessage('This is a message');
```

or even

```
use DebugBar\DebugBar;
....
DebugBar::info('this is info');
```

but I'm getting the following error.

```
Call to undefined method DebugBar\DebugBar::info()
```

my app.php has the following.

```
'providers' => [
.....
'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider',
....


'aliases' => [ 
....
'DebugBar'  => 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade',
```

I'm still a Laravel newbie, so not sure where to check next.  I've checked the documentation on both  http://phpdebugbar.com/docs/ and https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar but I think I'm just missing something.

Comment: Debugbar vs DebugBar maybe?

Comment: I tried that after posting this, no change.  I'll go ahead and make that edit though.

Comment: After defining your service provider and facade with the name `Debugbar` (not `DebugBar`, simply use `\Debugbar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you use the provider-array in a wrong way. It should be:

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,
]
```

in your `config/app.php`. Also, please use the following instead of the string you wrote above:

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'DebugBar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,
]
```

I tried your config on a clean Laravel-5 installation and it did not work.   This is comes possibly with the absolute class paths. With the config listed above, it works very well.

Comment: I copy\pasted what you have above, with `DebugBar::info('this is info');` still getting `Call to undefined method DebugBar\DebugBar::info()`   I will try a clean install of 5.1 later

Comment: Ugh... sorry, I've had a typo in my code. Of course it is `'DebugBar' => ...` instead of `'Debugbar' => ...`. After that you could update the classpath-file with `composer dump-autoload` and restart the dev-server `php artisan serve`

Comment: Alright!  With those changes you suggested, I also had to change `use DebugBar\DebugBar` to simply `use DebugBar` and that made it work. Thanks for the help martinweise!

Answer (score 6):

if you want to show DebugBar this this process :

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,
]
```

then

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'DebugBar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,
]
```

then in your controller write

```
app('debugbar')->error('Watch out..');
```

now refresh browser then see the message enjoy

Comment: Don't know why but this worked for me instead of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

For me, auto-injecting `DebugBar\DebugBar` as suggested by my IDE did not automatically work, but gave this error. Changing it to `Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade as DebugBar` solved the problem. Seems that there is a totally different package named "DebugBar" installed in the default Laravel configuration.

So, if in the beginning of file you see:

```php
use DebugBar\DebugBar;
```

Change it to:

```php
use Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade as DebugBar;
```

Also, if registered as a facade, you can always use `\DebugBar::addMessage('This is a message');` etc. without injecting it first, as you have told Laravel how to resolve the class. This way you need not to `use` it first.

Answer (score 0):

Also make be sure that `Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class`, is first in providers list.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `.env` :

```
DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=true
```