# Laravel debugbar not displaying messages

Tags: laravel, debugging

I have debugbar installed, and it is showing up. However, whenever I try to send a message to the console:

```
use Debugbar\Debugbar;
....
Debugbar::info('this is info');
```

I get this error:

```
Call to undefined method Debugbar\Debugbar::info()
```

I have the following in my app.php:

```
'providers' =>
Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,
'aliases' => 
'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class
```

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161978/laravel-debugbar-messages-not-showing) but after following all the advice in the discussion, the problem still persists. If I try to call to call Debugbar like this:

```
app('debugbar')->error('Watch out..');
```

There is no error, but the message still does not appear

Comment: What happens when you `return dd(new Debugbar)`? Make sure to include alias, `use Debugbar`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I walked away from my computer for an hour came back, and it worked. Nothing had changed! I still have no idea why. Perhaps    caching had something to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

Change `use Debugbar\Debugbar;` to `use Debugbar;`

Comment: Its not an either or situation. This is definitely **one** of the errors!